# Azure deployment from source without TFS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, deployment

Does anyone knows if the deployment from source feature of Azure is intended to work with .NET projects ?
I mean, if I put source code in the local git repository of Azure and then trigger a deploy, is my source code going to be compiled and then deployed or are my source files simply going to be copied ?

We are managing our source code, tasks etc... on Codebasehq and would like to use azure as a deployment platform only. What I'm trying to achieve is push a release-ready code on the Azure git repository, and get it built and deployed. Relevant resources would be very welcome, I haven't been able to find an answer so far.

Thanks

Comment: You can deploy from Visual Studio using Publish (right click on the project to publish). That's pretty slick.  TFS continuous integration is slick as well. As for Git, the problem is that you need a 3rd party to build and deploy after pushing.  Recommendations for such are off topic.

Comment: Thanks. I know all of that, you are not addressing my question

Comment: ***Recommendations for such are off topic.***

Comment: @Will I'm not asking for a recommendation, I'm asking whether or not a feature is supported in Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build and deploy from git to azure, try this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

**update** 
I take it back, this link will help you setup everything and will build the project as well http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2014/03/31/deploying-an-azure-web-site-using-git-and-continuous-integration.aspx

Or you could setup TeamCity to do the building of the project and then use MS Deploy from team city to push the build to azure

**update 2**
There is a difference between TFS and TFS Online, the answer is no if the question is referring to TFS Online and the particular feature you're talking about. If you have a server in office handy you could use that to build and deploy.

Comment: Thanks I've seen this page but I wasn't sure it was going to build the code, do you confirm the code will be built ? I was indeed specifically talking about this feature

Comment: So basically the answer to my question is no, this feature won't build anything. It's mainly useful for PHP  projects etc.. that do not require build